# May I avoid new line for subsubsections?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{The title}
\subsection{A subtitle}
\subsubsection{}
\subsubsection{}
\end{document}
```

How may I get subsubsection 1.1.2 to begin just after the last period sign of the last sentence of subsubsection 1.1.1?

Comment: it would help people test answers if your test document had had the case described in the question, with some text and a full stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\quad\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\textbf{\thesubsubsection}\ }

\begin{document}
\section{The title}
Zzz zzz zzz.
\subsection{A subtitle}
Zzz zzz zzz.
\subsubsection{}
Zzz zzz zzz.
\subsubsection{}
Zzz zzz zzz.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would it be with paragraph instead of subsubsection?

Comment: @Sapiens just change `subsubsection` to `paragraph` in the three places it appears in the definition