# May we avoid the line break after section title?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, sections-paragraphs, section-titles

I would like to avoid the mandatory line break after \section{title}, so that the text after \section{title} continues on the same line.

One way to answer the question may proceed by modifying David Carlisle's answer to my question [May I avoid new line for subsubsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577292/may-i-avoid-new-line-for-subsubsections), and I did not succeed with that.

The MWE makes the question more precise:

```
\documentclass[]{article}



\begin{document}

The command $\backslash$section\{title\} text
gives the text below the section title, as follows:

\section{title} text


\noindent Is there a way to cheat so that we may use something like the command

\medskip

$\backslash$cheatsection\{title\} text 


to appear like the following: 

\medskip


\noindent{\Large \textbf{2\indent text}}? 




\end{document}
```

Comment: my answer was avoiding the break _before_ the heading avoiding the break _after_ is just a standard latex run-in heading like `\paragraph` you can use that for `\section` by changing the sign in its definition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "avoiding the break after is just a standard latex run-in heading like \paragraph you can use that for \section by changing the sign in its definition "

Unfortunately, I do not understand how I may change the sign in the definition of \section to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did attempt to emulate your previous answer, but as I mentioned, I did not succeed. Just substituting with "section" for "subsubsection" generates a flood of errors with me.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215863/how-to-have-run-in-section-in-a-separate-command/215864#215864

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great! That solved my problem. :)